# Specifying X windows' geometry in the coordinates obtained from  wmctrl

Tags: gnome-terminal, xorg

In the [X documentation](http://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.6/doc/man/man7/X.7.xhtml#heading7) I read that the `Width`, `Height`, `Xposition` and `Yposition` coordinates must be specified in terminal characters when using:

`gnome-terminal --geometry=WidthxHeight+Xposition+Yposition`

If I use as input coordinates those that I get from a `wmctrl -lG` output (not sure if `wmctrl` uses pixels, terminal characters or something different as geometrical units), I don't get the expected results. I.e. the geometry coordinates output by `wmctrl -lG` and the ones a user can specify with `gnome-terminal --geometry` turn out to be different.

Is there anything I am doing wrong? Any thoughts?

Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `--geometry` option for `gnome-terminal` is actually measured in characters, rather than pixels. For example, to get an 80 column terminal only 10 lines high, you can launch `gnome-terminal` like this:

```
gnome-terminal --geometry 80x10
```

The terminal will resize in increments of the font character size, which it communicates to the Xserver using `WM_NORMAL_HINTS`. You can examine these using the `xprop` command. For example, here I find a Terminal window id, and ask xprop about it:

```
$ wmctrl -lG | tail -n1
0x06400021  0 592  314  580  338  myhostname kees@myhostname: ~
$ xprop -id 0x6400021
...
WM_NORMAL_HINTS(WM_SIZE_HINTS):
        program specified minimum size: 48 by 16
        program specified resize increment: 7 by 14
        program specified base size: 20 by 2
        window gravity: NorthWest
...
```

In the above case, the font size is 7 by 14 pixels. So if I wanted a 70 by 140 pixel Terminal, I could run `gnome-terminal --geometry 10x10` (though it would be 20 x 2 pixels larger than that based on the window manager decorations, etc, as seen in the "specific base size" above).

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 21.10 I've found it does seem to be pixel-based not character-based, although uhhh virtual pixels not literal pixels (I'm using a 4k monitor but I have 2x scaling turned on in Screen Display, and I'm giving the geometry as if 1080p)

and I found that there were issues where it would jump down and shrink if I made it the full 1080 pixels, due to the status bar, and in practice there seems to be a couple pixels of extra border needed.

so my command for launching two terminals that together fill my lower monitor ends up looking like this (`958` instead of `960`, and `1028` instead of `1080` (to account for the status bar)

```
gnome-terminal --window-with-profile=Node --geometry=958x1028+0+1080 -- bash & 
gnome-terminal --window-with-profile=Git --geometry=958x1028+960+1080 -- bash
```

Answer (score -1):

The command `gnome-terminal --geometry 80x10` does not work in Ubuntu.

You must use a `=` after `geometry`, not a space: `gnome-terminal --geometry=80x10+10+10`

Comment: works for me either way (ubuntu 20.04)