# How do I start gnome-terminal with a specific width/height?

Tags: launcher, gnome-terminal, .desktop

I would like to configure gnome-terminal to start with a bigger window by default. How do I do it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`man gnome-terminal` reveals that this is the way:

```
gnome-terminal --geometry=20x20
```

The above will create a 20x20 window (measured in characters, see [Specifying X windows' geometry in the coordinates obtained from  wmctrl](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32848/specifying-x-windows-geometry-in-the-coordinates-obtained-from-wmctrl))

Answer (score 11):

You can edit the Profile of the Gnome Terminal by going to the Global Menu, option Edit/Preferences in which you can enable the "Use custom default terminal size" and set the default columns and rows size as shown in this screenshot:

[image: screenshot of Profile settings window]

The modifications you make to your Profile will take effect the next time you open a terminal.

Comment: +1 This is the correct answer the the question, "I would like to configure gnome-terminal to start with a bigger window by default. How do  do it?"  The accepted answer does not alter the default terminal size.

Comment: @whitebeard agree, can I somehow deny the acceptance of my answer?

Answer (score 2):

Gnome Terminal has changed since [@Geppettvs](https://askubuntu.com/a/333005/689894)' answer 8 years ago.

In GNOME Shell 3.36.7 you are still able to change initial size, as explained in `gnome-terminal`'s [Terminal sizes help](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-terminal/stable/app-terminal-sizes.html.en):

> If you require custom size Terminal windows, you can also set the default window size according to your requirements:
>
> 1. Press the menu button in the top-right corner of the window and select Preferences.
> 2. In the sidebar, select your current profile in the Profiles section.
> 3. Select Text.
> 4. Set Initial terminal size by typing the desired number of columns and rows in the corresponding input boxes. You can also click + to increase or - to decrease the size.

The **Edit** > **Preferences** menu also looks different:

[image: screenshot of Preferences window showing current profile > Text]