# Is it possible to run a TTY in X session?

Tags: xorg, session, virtual-console

I want to try some **svgalib** graphical examples which switches to one of the **tty**s other than **tty7**. Instead I want  to try it in a graphical X session which I logged in to the current desktop. I need to run a virtual terminal in fixed size (say 100x100) in the current desktop that is attached to **tty** without switching to full screen.

Because I tried Xnest to reach one of the **tty**s but I met another failure [Xnest switches to full screen when I start startx in it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/780335/xnest-switches-to-full-screen-when-i-start-startx-in-it)

I've found out that it's not possible to launch **virtual terminal** which uses,
say **tty3**,  in graphical desktop X session.

Is it possible?

EDIT: I want to use it in the desktop session because I can not reach **ctrl+alt+f4** shortcuts for some reason.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? ```gnome-terminal --geometry=100x100``` It starts a virtual terminal in a fixed size of 100x100. Source: https://askubuntu.com/a/332992/549416