# Xnest switches to full screen when I start startx in it

Tags: xorg, session, virtual-console

I launch **Xnest** with

```
Xnest -ac :1  -geometry 800x600
```

then I can run `xclock` in it from another terminal with

```
DISPLAY=:1 xclock
```

but when I attempt to start X session in it from another terminal with

```
DISPLAY=:1 startx
```

`Xnest` window switches to full screen but does nothing except blinking cursor. I do not want it to switch to full screen.

Would anybody tell me how to do that?